# system() function in C++ works fine for some time and fails some time returning -1 due to ECHILD error.Why?

Tags: c++, system

I am executing system() function in C++ for every 5 minutes. It works fine for some time and fails some time returning -1 due to ECHILD error.why is this issue happening sometimes?.To avoid this I set SIGCHLD to SIG_DFL, after this it is working fine. But there is a handler for  SIGCHLD in the program for other functions. Is there any effect on other functions in setting SIGCHLD to SIG_DFL?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. If other code depends on there being a handler for SIGCHLD and you suppress it, then there are likely to be problems. It isn't clear that you can even set SIGCHLD handling to SIG_DFL for the duration of the `system()` call; the signals might arrive while the function is executing.

Comment: In the instances where it fails, does the command actually get executed? Or does it fail before the command executes?

Comment: During execution of the command, SIGCHLD will be blocked

Comment: It is failing after executing sytem command(system("sar -r >/tmp/sarfile")). I checked the time stamp of sar file. At the same time the command returned -1. Is it due to SIGCHLD handler in program?How to handle this situation?

Answer (score 2):

Probably what you should do is to set SIGCHLD to SIG_DFL before calling system(), then re-register your SIGCHLD handler after system() returns.

But maybe more than that, you should think hard about why you are calling system() at all.  It's usually not the best tool for the job.